# Snowflake: Why would I choose to create an external stage when I can simply copy values into a table directly?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Why would I choose to create an external stage in Snowlflake when I can simply copy values into a table directly?

For instance, if I can do this:

```
create or replace TABLE EXAMPLE_DB.PUBLIC.USERS (
    ID INT,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR,
    EMAIL VARCHAR
);

copy into EXAMPLE_DB.PUBLIC.USERS
    from s3://mybucket/users.csv
    file_format = (
        type = csv
        field_delimiter = ','
        skip_header = 1
    );
```

Why would I ever decide to take the intermediate step of creating an external stage as in:

```
create or replace STAGE EXAMPLE_DB.PUBLIC.USER_STAGE
    url='s3://mybucket';

copy into EXAMPLE_DB.PUBLIC.USERS
    FROM @STAGE EXAMPLE_DB.PUBLIC.USER_STAGE
    file_format= (type = csv field_delimiter=',' skip_header=1)
    files = ('users.csv');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two reasons are maintenance and DRY rule:

[Creating an Azure Stage - External Stages](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-create-stage.html#external-stages):

> In addition to loading directly from files in Azure containers,
> Snowflake supports creating named external stages, **which encapsulate
> all of the required information for staging files**, including:
>
> - The Azure container where the files are staged.
> - The named storage integration object or Azure credentials for the container (if it is protected).
> - An encryption key (if the files in the container have been encrypted).
>
> **Named external stages are optional, but recommended when you plan to
> load data regularly from the same location**

---

Similiar applies for S3:

[Creating an S3 Stage - External Stage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-create-stage.html#external-stages):

> In addition to loading directly from files in S3 buckets, Snowflake
> supports creating named external stages, which encapsulate all of the
> required information for staging files, including:
>
> - The S3 bucket where the files are staged.
> - The named storage integration object or S3 credentials for the bucket (if it is protected).
> - An encryption key (if the files in the bucket have been encrypted).
>
> **Named external stages are optional, but recommended when you plan to
> load data regularly from the same location.**